# How should I deal with feelings of discomfort related to race?

Tags: interpersonal-issues

I need a specific class to graduate.  However, it's only taught by a single instructor who happens to be of a demographic group that I'm uncomfortable around.

How could I complete the required coursework given this discomfort?

Comment: Because I'm sure that this question'll get a lot of rude/abusive flags: folks, please consider that questions like this can be teaching opportunities.

Comment: @Nat I read this question many times (the original version). I am inclined to think it's troll. Of course, I cannot be sure. I am going to wait and see. In order to respect your opinion, I take no action on this post (no flag nor vote to close)

Comment: It is not a troll. I would appreciate some actual help.

Comment: This seems to be all about YOUR attitude - as you have not mentioned any action on the part of the professor that is outside of the normal professorial behaviour - you need to do some learning...

Comment: @Nat There is little evidence that this turned out to be a "teaching moment." And I think your edits significantly distort the content of the question. If OP is worried that some old white dude teaches the course "Intersectional feminism in the context of the BLM-movement", OP might feel uncomfortable with the demographic group of the instructor too, but the context would be very different. Does the world really need more racists in "Business Management?"

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker We need less hatred in the world.  Even if someone's a raging bigot, what good would come from suppressing them and encouraging them to brood on their feelings in isolation?  It seems that humanity would be better served if we try to encourage understanding.

Comment: Hopefully, I'm not going out on too much of a limb here: it is highly doubtful that a graduate student would encounter such a problem, even if said student was racist, simply because the stakes in graduate school are higher for the student and one would hope that a serious grad student would have the right mind to push through the experience. Voting to close.

Comment: I am an undergraduate

Comment: Please [edit] your question to elaborate *why* you are feeling uncomfortable and what exact problems you have. Otherwise answering this is a broad guessing game.

Comment: _I am an undergraduate_ -- Yes, I am aware of that (your question is tagged as such). My comment was about why your situation is unlikely to apply to grad students as well (situations that undergraduates find themselves in are not on topic here unless they can also apply to grad students).

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker I am not sure that your or anyone else's judgement regarding the necessity of such people in BM is needed. As long as they are following the rules of the program, there should be no obstructions for them to get the degree (on the other hand, it is possible that the rules of the program ban such attitudes but I have not seen any evidence of that from your comment).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You wouldn't be the first student ever to feel uncomfortable around an instructor due to demographic membership.  In this case, it may be due to race.  In others, I've seen students who've been sexually assaulted by the other gender feel uncomfortable around instructors of that gender.  These feelings are unfortunate, though they seem to happen in the real world.

It's kind of an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), though.  We have overwhelming empirical evidence that instructors of all races can be excellent teachers.  This is, it's unlikely that the instructor's race is the true problem; rather, we might consider the unpleasant feelings about race to be the true issue.

You might consider reflecting on your feelings about race and specifically why it's a problem for you.  Professional counselling may help to reveal the issue.  And depending on your institution, such services may already be offered to students.

In the long run, it'd seem healthiest for you to learn how you truly feel and seek to address whatever emotional causation this particular situation may reflect.

Comment: The above answer is a quick one that I haven't had time to fully consider yet.  Ideally, this sort of question would be addressed more thoroughly.  Just trying to help guide the issue in the right direction, such that a teaching moment isn't lost.

Comment: You're right. I think I'll drop the class and hope for better luck next semester. Delaying my graduation won't hurt that much, my parents will pay for everything.

Comment: @user87174 Do you really feel that uncomfortable around the other racial group?  I mean, honestly, that seems like a pretty big long-term problem that'd be healthier to address sooner than later.

Comment: @user87174 think long term: I assume you want to have a fulfilling job. Do you really think you can avoid interacting with people from a specific racial group for the rest of your life? Right now is the time to deal with these issues, before they are going to seriously hinder your career. This is what professional counselors are for. Once you graduate it will only be much harder to make use of such services. So now is the time to do something about it: Get help, and don't drop out of that course.

Answer (score 10):

Take the class with this professor.  You are most likely uncomfortable with this professor's race because of minimal exposure to interactions with this person's race.  The real world is full of people that are different than you, and becoming comfortable with that is part of being an adult.  Interacting with people that are different than you, whether it be race, sexual orientation, religion, etc. will help you grow as a person and open your world view, which is a huge part of the purpose of college in the first place.